# SQL - Help on re-arranging data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have done a unpivot and this the result, row_number was added after unpivot using the `row_number()`.

```
Name    ID      Label       Value   Row_Number
A       101     Label1      11          1
A       101     Label2      20          2
A       101     Label3      16          3
B       102     Label1      17          1
B       102     Label2      19          2
B       102     Label3      12          3
B       102     Label4      17          4
C       103     Label1      15          1
C       103     Label2      16          2
```

I need some help on removing the entire row where the row_number is 1 and adding only `Label` and `Value` columns value to a new column. Likely the result to be like the table below.

```
Name    ID      Label       Value   Row_Number  New Label   New Value
A       101     Label2      20          2       Label1          11
A       101     Label3      16          3           
B       102     Label2      19          2       Label1          17
B       102     Label3      12          3           
B       102     Label4      17          4           
C       103     Label2      16          2       Label1          15
```

I thought of doing this like, storing all the records where row_number >= 2 into a temp table. And the storing all the values where row_number = 1 into another temp table. And join the data using `Name` and `ID`.

And at the same time, I was thinking that this isn't a robust way of doing it, any suggestion will help me whether I wanted to go this solution or is there any other better way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what you said, using CTE instead of temp table

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT Name, ID, Label, Value
    FROM <<Table>>
    WHERE Row_Number = 1
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT Name, ID, Label, Value, Row_Number
    FROM <<Table>>
    WHERE Row_Number > 1
)
SELECT
    cte2.Name, cte2.ID, cte2.Label, cte2.Row_Number,
    cte1.Label AS New_Label, cte1.Value AS New_Value
FROM
    cte1 LEFT JOIN cte2 ON cte1.ID =cte2.ID AND cte2.Row_Number=2
```

Answer (score 0):

*Is your input data in your question real not dummy ?*

**If Yes,**

Use `Case` statement with `Sub-query` like the next demo:-

```
Create table #temp (Name char(1),ID int, Label varchar(10), Value int,Row_Number int)
go
insert into #temp values('A',101,'Label1', 11,1)
insert into #temp values('A',101,'Label2', 20,2)
insert into #temp values('A',101,'Label3', 16,3)
insert into #temp values('B',102,'Label1', 17,1)
insert into #temp values('B',102,'Label2', 19,2)
insert into #temp values('B',102,'Label3', 12,3)
insert into #temp values('B',102,'Label4', 17,4)
insert into #temp values('C',103,'Label1', 15,1)
insert into #temp values('C',103,'Label2', 16,2)
go

select Name,ID,Label,value,Row_Number , [New Label] , [New value] 
from (
    select Name,ID,Label,value,Row_Number, 
    case Label  when 'Label2' then 'Label1' end as [New Label],
    case Label  when 'Label2' then  (select value from #temp 
    where name = b.Name
    and Label = 'Label1'
    ) end as [New value] 
    from #temp b
) a
where Label <>  'Label1'
```

**Result:-**

[image]